# How to compare 2 values and take an action based on the result in ansible

Tags: ansible, jinja2, ansible-2.x

I would like to compare 2 values based on a key and take an action accordingly.
Below is the input json, in this i would like to compare between **gpmgmt>L_123456> 101** with **gpmgmtcurrent>L_123456> 101**. In this case both values are **101**, so no action is needed. But the second JSON the values are  **101 & 103** and hence an action is needed. How do i loop over the values and take an action if there is a difference.

Input JSON(gpidmgmt):

```
{
    "changed": false,
    "msg": "All items completed",
    "results": [
        {
            "ansible_facts": {
                "gpmgmt": [
                    {
                        "L_123456": [
                            "101"
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "gpmgmtcurrent": {
                    "L_123456": [
                        "101"
                    ]
                }
            },
            "ansible_loop_var": "item",
            "changed": false,
            "failed": false,
            "item": "L_123456"
        },
        {
            "ansible_facts": {
                "gpmgmt": [
                    {
                        "N_1188779": [
                            "103"
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "gpmgmtcurrent": {
                    "N_1188779": [
                        "101"
                    ]
                }
            },
            "ansible_loop_var": "item",
            "changed": false,
            "failed": false,
            "item": "N_1188779"
        }
    ],
    "skipped": false
}
```

**Code: To take out the value of gpmgmt & gpmgmtcurrent:**

```
- name: GP Info
      set_fact:
         gplisttest: "{{gpidmgmt | json_query(gpmquerytest) }}"
         gplisttest1: "{{gpidmgmt | json_query(gpmquerytest1) }}"
      vars:
        gpmquerytest:  "results[*].ansible_facts.gpmgmt[].{{ item }}"
        gpmquerytest1:  "results[*].ansible_facts.gpmgmtcurrent.{{ item }}"
      with_items: "{{ gpnet }}"
      register: gpidmgmttest
```

**gpnet:**

```
[
    [
        "L_662029145223476760",
        "N_782500435255632820"
    ]
]
```

Comment: You need  to use the commands loop and when.
https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_conditionals.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Iterate with subelements because *gpmgmt* is a list. Get the key from *gpmgmtcurrent* and compare the lists, e.g.

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ _key }}: {{ _gpmgmt }} is NOT equal to {{ _gpmgmt_current }}"
      with_subelements:
        - "{{ gpidmgmt.results|map(attribute='ansible_facts')|list }}"
        - gpmgmt
      vars:
        _key: "{{ item.0.gpmgmtcurrent.keys()|first }}"
        _gpmgmt: "{{ item.1[_key] }}"
        _gpmgmt_current: "{{ item.0.gpmgmtcurrent[_key] }}"
      when: _gpmgmt|difference(_gpmgmt_current)|length > 0
```

gives

```yaml
  msg: 'N_1188779: [''103''] is NOT equal to [''101'']'
```